# Django error "no module named follow" on Windows, what's causing this?

Tags: python, django, windows, python-imaging-library, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to run a project a friend sent me using Win7x64 with python 2.7 and Django 1.4/1.3

My friend has a similar setup so it should work but it doesn't. At first I thought it was because I'm using 1.4 instead of 1.3 like he did, but nope same weird error

"Error: no module named follow" zero results in google...

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your project use something like [django-follow](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-follow)?

Check the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and for hints in `urls.py` that indicate this. Ask your friend to do a `pip freeze` in their project folder and send you the output or to generate a `requirements.txt` from the output of the `pip freeze` which will show all project dependencies.

If `django-follow` is the only missing thing then you can resolve it with `pip install django-follow`. Else you should also be installing the other dependencies.